# Chosen jquery plugin - displaying only "sub-options" from selected option

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I know this may sound simple, but I have 10 years experience in PHP/HTML and very limited skills in Javascript; therefore, I need some help.

I have a form where user needs to select a client (1st dropdown) and membership number (2nd dropdown). So I use PHP functions like those:

```
$res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from clients");
```

and

```
$res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from memberships");
```

Since both dropdowns contain many records, I installed Chosen plugin to make it easier (user just types client name and the dropdown list becomes very short). I can do exactly the same for 2nd dropdown (memberships), but I want to display only membership numbers of selected client.

So if user selects record "client 5" in 1st dropdown, I want 2nd dropdown to contain only memberships from "client 5". Put simply, once user selects a record from clients dropdown, PHP function should use query like this:

```
$res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from memberships where client_id='$selected_client_id'");
```

Any suggestions? I guess it has something to do with Chosen change/update events, but have no idea how to make it work in real life.

Comment: are you using ajax for push data to the 2nd dropdown?

Comment: I don't use any Ajax yet, since I don't know how to "push" data. I had a PHP/HTML form and simply installed Chosen plugin to make dropdowns easier to use.

Comment: U can use php for load 1st dropdown data. But for the second one, you may need to use ajax. And then have to call the chosen function

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Any code snippet for the second one?

Comment: After some search for pushing data via ajax (thanks for suggestion), I think this should help - http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list3.php